# Всегда выдает, что недостаточно средств

Tags: java, if

Почему программа всегда говорит, что недостаточно средств?

```
package ATM;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MoneyLogic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int money[] = {20, 50, 100};
        System.out.println("Введите количество вносимых денег (20, 50, 100)");
        CashIn cash = new CashIn(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt());


        System.out.println("Введите сумму, которую необходимо снять");
        int sum = sc.nextInt();
        int a = sum / money[2];

        if (sum > cash.moneyInATM) {
            System.out.println("В банкомате недостаточно средств");

        } else if (sum < 20 || sum == 30 || sum % 10 != 0) {
            System.out.println("Невозможно выдать такую сумму");

        } else if (sum % money[2] == 0) {
            System.out.println(sum / money[2] + " * 100 рублей");
        } else {
            if ((sum % money[2]) % 20 == 0) {
                System.out.println(a + " * 100 рублей, " +
                        (sum % money[2]) / money[0] + " * 20 рублей");
            } else {
                System.out.println((a - 1) + " * 100 рублей, " + 1 + " * 50 рублей, " +
                        ((sum - (a - 1) * 100 - 50) / money[0]) + " * 20 рублей");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Класс с конструктором

```
package ATM;

public class CashIn {

    private int twenty;
    private int fifty;
    private int hundred;
    protected int moneyInATM;

    //Метод для ввода количества купюр, и вывода общей суммы
    public CashIn(int twenty, int fifty, int hundred) {
        this.twenty = twenty * 20;
        this.fifty = fifty * 50;
        this.hundred = hundred * 100;
        int moneyInATM = this.hundred + this.fifty + this.twenty;
        System.out.println(this.twenty + " рублей купюрами по 20");
        System.out.println(this.fifty + " рублей купюрами по 50");
        System.out.println(this.hundred + " рублей купюрами по 100");
        System.out.println("Всего в банкомате " + (moneyInATM) + " рублей");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

И второй вопрос, если получится с этим разобраться, как после сообщения о невозможности снятия вернуться к вводу суммы? Спасибо

Comment: Ну выведи cash.moneyInATM сразу после инициализации и перед if. Что там?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public CashIn(int twenty, int fifty, int hundred) {
    this.twenty = twenty * 20;
    this.fifty = fifty * 50;
    this.hundred = hundred * 100;
    /*int !!!*/ moneyInATM = this.hundred + this.fifty + this.twenty;
    ...
```

> не очень понятно почему это мешало

У вас в конструкторе была объявлена локальная переменная `moneyInATM`, а член класса `moneyInATM` оставался равен нулю.

> вернуться к вводу суммы(можно ли это сделать без цикла?)

Чем провинился цикл? Не хотите цикл - используйте рекурсию.

Comment: да, помогло, спасибо =)

Comment: правда не очень понятно почему это мешало =)
может быть подскажете и со вторым вопросом.
Как после сообщения о невозможности снятия вернуться к вводу суммы(можно ли это сделать без цикла?). Спасибо